# PHP: For loop, how do I set a variable as a maximum?

Tags: php, for-loop, type-conversion

I am trying to be able to make a loop that lets me place stars on a website, to show a rating (1 to 5) on the website, that you can put down with fields. However, I do not know how to convert the field correctly.

I am using WordPress with Custom Field types, this is were I define the variable.

I have a variable that I get from somewhere else, and I have tried the following two ways:

```
<?php
    $star = intval(the_field('rating'));
    for ($i=0; $i < $star; $i++){
        intval(the_field('rating'));
    }
?>
```

and the second one:

```
<?php
    $star = number_format(the_field('rating');
    for ($i=0; $i < $star; $i++){
        number_format(the_field('rating'));
    }
?>
```

Thank you very much for you help in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `the_field('rating')` and what do you want to display?

Comment: on the page i am testing it on it is '4',
i want to be able to show stars for making the rating of the page visible
in the end i should be able to display the the_field('rating') should be the number of full stars displayed, and 1 - that number, would be the number of empty stars displayed

Comment: What's the code that would show 1 star?

Comment: that is what the loop should do as well
just going through it for one full star once, and then another 4 empty ones, there will always be at least 1 full star and at max 5 (i already made sure of that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `the_field` echos the value, you need `get_field` to return the value.  Then just repeat whatever string you're using to display a star or empty star:

```
$stars = get_field('rating');
echo str_repeat('*', $stars) . str_repeat('O', 5-$stars);
```

With a loop just check if your counter is less than or equal to the star rating:

```
$stars = get_field('rating');

for ($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++){
    echo ($i <= $stars) ? "*" : "O";
}
```

Comment: This still gives me the same problem as with my loop.
The first one is done once and the second one is done 5 times
thank you though

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking then.  It works https://3v4l.org/SqDBS

Comment: yeah, if you put down a number it works just fine, but it doesnt work with the_field('rating'), my question is how to get that to work

Comment: `var_dump(the_field('rating'));` and we can see.

Comment: it returns: [the number i put in]NULL, for example: 4NULL